# AFNetworking JSONRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

`AFJSONRequestOperation` has a `successBlock` block for when the request succeeds, but there is no way to set the "Authentication Block" other than on the operation itself, so if that fails then there is no way to send back to the caller of the `AFJSONRequestOperation`. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

I would expect to be able to tell the caller that the whole operation failed because authorization failed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the method takes two block as a parameters success and failure

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
```

So in the failure block you should be able to notify the caller of the failure

Comment: If you provide a `[operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock]` and that fails, the `failure` block does not fire.